# Output table formatted data to console

Tags: java, text

Does anyone know of a Java library or built in that I can use to format data into a table suitable for printing to the console?

I know about string justification and padding using String.format, but I'm looking for something that automatically adjusts the column width to the data, similar to the `column` command on BSD systems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format tabular data as text in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913765/how-to-format-tabular-data-as-text-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format tabular data as text in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913765/how-to-format-tabular-data-as-text-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format` and use `Apache StringUtils.center()` to automatically pad the text to center it in the cell:

https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html